# how do i remove the full screen icon or deactivate in kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

**my default size. I don't want the size to change**

```
Window.size = (800,700)
```

**I tried them but they don't work**

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '700')
Config.write()

Window.size = (800,700)
```

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
```

can anyone help me